# Too many possibilities for categorical fields

Tags: pandas, machine-learning, categorical-data

I have 40 input categorical fields such as 
"CpuModel" (1523 possibilities)

each of them could have thousands of possibilities.

If I use get_dummies, my panda table will contain many dummy columns.
This fields I am planning to use as input features for machine learning algorithms.

How should I handle this?

Answer (score 0):

in that case you should use labelencoder. 
 using it on categorical column will return a column with numerical values that represent the frequency count of those variables.

reference: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html

hope that helps!

Comment: no idea. wld have to read documentation. as to accuracy, my advice would be test both, use the one that gives the best result.